# Fields of characteristic $p$ that are isomorphic as vector spaces, but not as fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Give an example of a field $\mathbb{K}$ of characteristic $p > 0$ and elements $a,b \in \bar{\mathbb{K}}$, such that $\mathbb{K}(a)$ and $\mathbb{K}(b)$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{K}$, but not isomorphic as fields.

I was thinking of $\mathbb{F}_2(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{F}_2(\sqrt{3})$...

Comment: Uhm $2=0$ and $3 =1$ in $F_2$. You need another idea.

Comment: @quid Yes, but both extensions has degree two and {1 ,  $\sqrt{2}$ } and {1 ,  $\sqrt{3}$ } as basis, and are over the same field...

Comment: No they are not extensions of degree two. They are just $F_2$ again. Anyway you can forget about using $K$ a finite field as a finite field is determined by its cardinality. So it $K(a)$ and $K(b)$ are iso a vector space in this case they have same cardinality.

Comment: I got it. You are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given two finite fields $E_1$ and $E_2$ that are both extensions of a field $\mathbb{K}$, we have that $$E_1\cong E_2 \text{ as fields} \iff \lvert E_1\rvert = \lvert E_2\rvert \iff E_1\cong E_2\text{ as $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces}$$
so you can't find any examples with $\mathbb{K}$ finite.

**Hint:** Try using the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{F}_p(T)$. For concreteness, let's use $p=2$. As long as the fields $\mathbb{K}(a)$ and $\mathbb{K}(b)$ have the same dimension as $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces, i.e., as long as $[\mathbb{K}(a):\mathbb{K}]=[\mathbb{K}(b):\mathbb{K}]$, they will be isomorphic as $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces. But you can choose $a$ and $b$ to be the roots of some very different irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{K}[x]$, like say perhaps $x^2-T$ and $x^2+x+1$, and you can prove the resulting fields are not isomorphic.

Comment: Well, to prove that are not isomorphic as field, i suppose that there is a isomorphism $\psi $: K(a) $\longrightarrow $K(b) as b²=T then $\psi^2 $(b)=T and $\psi $(b)=a therefore a²=T, but a²=-a-1 then -a-1=T and a=-T-1 and a is in K, contradiction, because a is not in K. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not correct. There is no reason that a (hypothetical) isomorphism from $\mathbb{K}(a)$ to $\mathbb{K}(b)$ would have to send $a$ to $b$. However, if we assume for the sake of contradiction that $\psi:\mathbb{K}(a)\to\mathbb{K}(b)$ is an isomorphism of fields, you can conclude that $\psi(a)$ is **some element** of the field $\mathbb{K}(b)$ satisfying the polynomial that $a$ does, and $\psi^{-1}(b)$ is **some element** of the field $\mathbb{K}(a)$ satisfying the polynomial that $b$ does. Can you prove that such elements do not exist?

Comment: I don't think so. But i had another ideia: Using the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ and p(x) = $x^2-T$ and q(x) = $x^2+Tx+1$ $\in \mathbb{K}[x]$. If $b \in \bar{\mathbb{K}}$ is a zero of p(x) = $x^2-T$ and $a \in \bar{\mathbb{K}}$ is a zero of q(x) = $x^2+Tx+1$ then p(x)=(x-b)² $\in \mathbb{K}(b)[x]$ is purely inseparable. Otherwise q'(x)=T so q(x) is separable and the same to $\mathbb{K}(a)$. So $\mathbb{K}(a)$ and $\mathbb{K}(b)$ can't be isomorphic as fields. What you think?

Comment: Your writing is somewhat convoluted, but yes, it is true that if $a$ is a root of $q=x^2+Tx+1$ and $b$ is a root of $x^2-T$, then $\mathbb{K}(a)$ is a separable extension of $\mathbb{K}$, and $\mathbb{K}(b)$ is a non-separable extension of $\mathbb{K}$. However this does not suffice to prove that they are not isomorphic as fields. For example, $\mathbb{C}$ (the complex numbers) and $\mathbb{C}(X)$ are not isomorphic as extensions of $\mathbb{C}$, but they are isomorphic as fields (since they are both isomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ adjoin continuum-many variables).

Comment: I see. Then i can only ask for more details from your answer above.

Comment: Zev, I think your two examples are both function fields of genus zero over $\Bbb F_2$. My examples would be $\Bbb F_2(T)$ itself and $\Bbb F_2(T)[Y]/(Y^2+Y+T^3)$. The latter is a ff of genus one, so definitely not isomorphic to the former.

Comment: Whoops: your examples are OK: the first is a genus-zero ff with constant field $\Bbb F_2$, the second is also genus zero, but the constant field is $\Bbb F_4$.

Comment: @Lubin: Still, your example is definitely a stronger one, very much worth pointing out.